# TS2564 Property mapViewEl has no initializer

Tags: angular, typescript, arcmap

I am working to get a ArcMap Javascript for Angular (v4) to display a map in a Angular (v10) project. All the code samples ([here](https://blog.jimdhughes.com/angular-esri-not-bad/), [ESRI Offical here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/angular/), and stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-arcgis-api4-x)) I have found are very similar. The viewChild is created like this :

```
export class EsriMapComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
@ViewChild("mapViewNode", { static: true }) private mapViewEl: ElementRef;
view: any;
constructor() { }
```

But my IDE informs me that `TS2564 Property mapViewEl has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor`.

I can change this line to :

```
@ViewChild("mapViewNode", { static: true }) private mapViewEl!: ElementRef;
```

And the map is drawn, but I don't like removing Typescript protection, especially since it is not done in any of the working samples I have found online.

The esri-map.component.html is very simple : `<div #mapViewNode></div>`.

How can I fix the TS2564 error?

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to use the optional operator (`?`) instead of not-null assertion (`!`). Because the property is actually `undefined` until the component is rendered, so, eventually you'll need to manage potentially `undefined` values in the property. Besides,  if the component name in `@ViewChild('compName')` is not correct the property will be `undefined` so if you mark it as optional It sounds more realistic than the `not-null` alternative.

```js
@ViewChild("mapViewNode", { static: true }) private mapViewEl?: ElementRef;
```